# Cypress - not visible element for cmd run

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

When I start my automated test with cmd (via command cypress run) test allways fails with typing in element. It says that element is not visible.
But when I start my test with browser it will allways pass.

[image]

Have someone same problem?

I can't change HTML code.

```
cy.get('#reasonRecommendationByAgent')
.type('Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
.should('have.value', 'Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
```

If I use force:true than test fails with this error message:

[image]

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: When you run cypress headed & headless, are you using the same browser? I know I had issues with it using electron vs chrome. and not only that but at times when I'd run it through the command line, it'd be using a different version of cypress, and therefore a different version of the browsers, versus when I ran cypress with the UI.

Comment: When it fails after 'force' is true, it looks like the element isn't in the DOM anymore -- is there anything that could possibly cause it to detach from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because it is masked by some other element. I have seen this happen in my own environment and solved it by simple adding the option 'force'. What you end up with is this:

```js
cy.get('#reasonRecommendationByAgent')
  .type('Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele', {force: true})
  .should('have.value', 'Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
```

Comment: That doesn't work. If I use force than test fails with error message that I attached to the head description

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding a should('be.visible'):

```
cy.get('#reasonRecommendationByAgent')
  .should('be.visible')
  .type('Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
  .should('have.value', 'Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
```